# RGBD Slam Stereo Setup

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi - I want to use RGBD Slam using a Stereo Setup.
I changed already the topics in the launch file, but when I start the RGBD GUI nothing happens.

Here is my launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="rgbdslam" type="rgbdslam" name="rgbdslam" cwd="node" required="true" output="log"> 

    <param name="config/camera_info_topic"             value="/stereo_camera/camera_info"/>
    <param name="config/wide_topic"                    value="/stereo_camera/left/image_mono"/>
    <param name="config/wide_cloud_topic"              value="/stereo_camera/points2"/>
```

[...]

```
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62304/rgbd-slam-stereo-setup/) by [Waterplant](https://answers.ros.org/users/4689/waterplant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been removed from RGBD slam for a while, so sorry if I lead you in a wrong direction. I think that your problem might be in the point cloud topic. Are you using the stereo_img_proc node? I think that using the /disparity topic worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [P.Naughton](https://answers.ros.org/users/2954/p.naughton/) with karma: 26 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1